# Is there an alternative expression for match in Rust?

Tags: rust

I know that when handling errors using `Result` and `Option`, it can be expressed more concisely by using `unwrap_or_else`, `unwrap_or_default`, etc. instead of `match`.

The following is an example of expressing the match expression more concisely using `unwrap`.

```
let engine_name = match config.engine_name {
    Some(name) => name,
    None => host_name.clone(),
};

->
let engine_name = config.engine_name
    .unwrap_or_else(|| host_name.clone());


let group_name = match config.group_name {
    Some(name) => name,
    None => String::from("")
};
->
let group_name = config.group_name.unwrap_or_default();
```

#### Questions

Is there a function I can use instead of `match` if I want to put a `return` statement instead of putting a different value when an error occurs?

```
let accept_service = ServiceBuilder::new().service(match AcceptService::new() {
    Ok(service) => service,
    Err(e) => return Err(format!("failed to bind server socket: {}", e).into()),
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`map_err()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) and the error propagation operator `?`:

```rust
ServiceBuilder::new()
    .service(AcceptService::new().map_err(|e| format!("failed to bind server socket: {}", e)?));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. If don't use a return value, it looks the same as `if let Err(e)` right? Do you prefer `map_err()` or `if let Err(e)`?

Comment: @yjlee If I only want to propagate the error I prefer `map_err()`, but this is subjective.